# Can't install windows 8.1 from usb on bios based pc

Tags: boot, usb, windows-8.1, bios

Trying the same usb on newer laptop succeeds. Tried different programs for creating bootable usb from iso -  Windows USB creation tool, Rufus, Lili. The result is the same - PC ignores usb and boots normally or gets stuck until i get usb stick out and restart.
Would be happy to get a solution.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the laptop? Does another USB key work?

Comment: yes, i tried another usb with ubuntu and it was installed successfully on my pc. The pc is desktop with gigabyte p35 ds-3l motherboard and latest bios

Comment: Do you see the USB stick under the HDD list when you press F12 (boot menu) at boot? When flashing a Windows ISO with Rufus, it should be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to make usb drive the first one in

[image: hard disk boot priority]

in [image: cmos setup utility menu]